# Unable to allocate 67.2 GiB for an array with shape (9013880778,) and data type float64

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

```
df = pd.read_csv('tech_clustring.csv')
df_tech = df.copy()
df_tech = df[df.Sector == ('Technology' or 'Communication Services')]
tech_scaled = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df_tech.iloc[:, 2:6])
cluster = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=5, metric='euclidean', linkage='ward')

#The error occurs on this line
tech_cluster = cluster.fit(tech_scaled)
```

```
df_tech
       Symbol      Sector  Open   High    Low  Close
2470     AAOI  Technology  2.15  2.160  2.120   2.13
2471     AAOI  Technology  2.13  2.300  2.130   2.21
2472     AAOI  Technology  2.20  2.240  2.130   2.13
2473     AAOI  Technology  2.13  2.130  1.950   2.00
2474     AAOI  Technology  1.96  1.980  1.870   1.95
...       ...         ...   ...    ...    ...    ...
955519    ZUO  Technology  8.51  8.620  8.390   8.61
955520    ZUO  Technology  8.58  8.680  8.350   8.42
955521    ZUO  Technology  8.44  9.030  8.295   9.01
955522    ZUO  Technology  9.15  9.331  8.820   8.89
955523    ZUO  Technology  8.96  8.960  8.580   8.69

[134268 rows x 6 columns]
```

The shape of `tech_scaled`:

```
tech_scaled.shape
(134268, 4)
```

The size of `tech_scaled`:

```
tech_scaled.nbytes
4296576
```

The full output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ahmed/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/iter_10.py", line 73, in <module>
    tech_cluster = cluster.fit(tech_scaled)
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 1152, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/_agglomerative.py", line 979, in fit
    return self._fit(X)
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/_agglomerative.py", line 1071, in _fit
    out = memory.cache(tree_builder)(
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/memory.py", line 353, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_param_validation.py", line 187, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/_agglomerative.py", line 295, in ward_tree
    out = hierarchy.ward(X)
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/cluster/hierarchy.py", line 833, in ward
    return linkage(y, method='ward', metric='euclidean')
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/cluster/hierarchy.py", line 1059, in linkage
    y = distance.pdist(y, metric)
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py", line 2220, in pdist
    return pdist_fn(X, out=out, **kwargs)
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 67.2 GiB for an array with shape (9013880778,) and data type float64
```

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. `df_tech = df.copy()` is pointless and makes it worse

Comment: I have multiple other `df` for other sectors, and even if I used `df_tech = pd.read_csv('tech_clustring.csv')` I still get the same error.

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing - at this point, do you? Why do you have double the data in memory? You immediately overwrite it with `df_tech = df[df.Sector == ('Technology' or 'Communication Services')]`. It's utterly pointless but doubles the RAM use

Comment: I also have some serious doubts about `df_tech = df[df.Sector == ('Technology' or 'Communication Services')]` actually working. If you fix the memory error, this is gonna blow up next

Comment: How would you suggest to select rows for `Technology` or `Communication Services` sector, and reduce memory usage?

Comment: `df_tech = df[(df.Sector == 'Technology') | (df.Sector == 'Communication Services')]`

Comment: I'm not whining or complaining. _You **double** your memory usage for no reason_. It's not me that has the issue. Read the file once and get rid of `df_tech = df.copy()` because it (as I whined and complained about) is pointless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line in the error message is important for understanding why this is running out of memory:

```
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/cluster/hierarchy.py", line 1059, in linkage
    y = distance.pdist(y, metric)
```

This is calling [scipy.spatial.distance.pdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html), which is calculating the distance between every vector in your dataset and every other vector. In order to return the results of this, it needs to allocate N<sup>2</sup>/2 array entries, where N is the number of vectors in your dataset.

This is [134268 * 134268 / 2 * 8 bytes in gibibytes = 67.16 GiB](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=134268+*+134268+%2F+2+*+8+bytes+in+gibibytes).

Since AgglomerativeClustering uses pdist, it cannot handle a dataset of this size with the amount of memory you have. Since this step is done before any linkage steps are done, this means that no matter what linkage is selected, AgglomerativeClustering will fail.

I suggest either:

1. Reducing dataset size, for example by selecting 1000 elements at random.
2. Using a clustering algorithm which can handle a dataset of this size. (KMeans, for example, can cluster this dataset.)